# Home page not displaying correctly in IE8

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

My [website's](http://www.indiacustomercare.com) home page isn't displaying correctly in IE8 8.0.7600.16385 and Opera. The right sidebar is mixing with left sidebar and moving down the page. I'm using the Garland theme and I've not changed anything in it.

But if I click any page and browse any non-home page then the right sidebar blocks are showing correctly in both opera and 8.

It's working fine in Firefox, Safari. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website isn't displaying correctly for me on any broswer, not even Firefox.

The `<div id="sidebar-right" class="sidebar">` on your site is rendering **inside** the `<div id="center">` which is causing your issue.

Comment: But I've checked  page.tpl.php. And the sidebar-right is supposed to come within #center. But other pages where it's working fine has #sidebar-right outside #center. Which tpl file is being used for my site first page and other pages?

Comment: @AgA: do you have a `page--front.tpl.php` file?  That would be the one being used for your front page.

Comment: No. I've also searched for any file containing text : id="center". I found: page-node-lightbox2.tpl.php,page.tpl.php, maintenance-page.tpl.php.